# fetching data in Next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

> You should not fetch an API route from getStaticProps — instead, you
> can write the server-side code directly in getStaticProps.

above sentence is from official docs of next.js and i find it confusing.
is it saying that i shouldn't do ajax request to my restful api? (i m using node express app as backend).
 i m new to next.js, before i was using react node app with mongodb as database. i used moongose package for database related queries.
 if i am not supposed to do ajax request then how am i supposed to work with data fetching related thing? can i use moongose in frontend directly?

```
//the way i want to do   
 getStaticProps(){
    //here i want to get data from database about posts
    //fetch('some end point of my restful api'){...}
    }
//the way i think official docs is telling me to do
     getStaticProps(){
        //query from database

    
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

API Routes are a NextJS feature that let you create a API - This requires the local server to be up and listening.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

`getStaticProps` are fetched at build time, means without user request. It lets *NextJS* generate SSR pages without needing a user request, API Routes wont be available at this time as the server hasn't started.

In your example

```
    //here i want to get data from database about posts
    //fetch('some end point of my restful api'){...}
```

```
// 1.Write your data from database 
// 2. Instead of `fetch` - Write logic of your restful api if 
its internal or the external endpoint that doesn't 
need the instantiation of your server.
```

Hope the difference makes sense, you can make `fetch` calls its just that they shouldn't be something your server itself is creating. Think of it like a build time fetch call.

Comment: so next.js lets me write backend code? can i use mongoose? thanks  i got my answer i have different api exposed as a backend for my app so i can call fetch the docs was talking about diiferent api route ie provided by next.js.am i right?

Comment: Correct, anything that is not created by the app itself - write your code to access mongoose there just be aware thay page creation may take longer during build time but pages can will be super fast!